# Need help aligning time series data in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, time, linear-algebra

So my friend and I ran an experiment 2 weeks ago and we've encountered something a bit weird. I should preface this by saying that I dont really program much so sorry if this is a dumb question and seems like a waste of time.

Let's say we have data-set A and data-set B (the experiment itself doesnt matter).  All of the times are given in fractional day. The format of the data should all match, but the time the data points were recorded for each set aren't necessarily aligned (they each have their own time vectors). For example, the measurements for data-set A are recorded every 100 ms. However, the instrument for data-set B  is averaging the data and only records a point once every minute or so. My problem here is aligning the time for the different types of data collected. For data-set A, the data and the time vectors have a length of 25042 (25042x1 double). Data-set B and its time vector have a length of 828 (828x1 double).

It comes down to the fact that I need to look at data set B, and find the times that correspond to peaks in the data. Those times are the only times of interest to me in data set A. This is why I need a way of aligning the time vectors/series and thus the data. If an exact solution isn't possible, even an approximation would be great help. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Find the difference between the consecutive points in B.

    C = B(2,end) - B(1,end-1)

When the sign changes from positive to negative in C, you have a peak.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two time vectors: `tA` and `tB`, and a vector of time indices `bIndices` that contains the known peak(s). This corresponds to time(s) `tB(bIndices(:))`. You need to loop through the entire vector `bIndices` searching again through the entire vector `tA(:)` FULLY each time until the time is greater-than-or-equal-to `tB(b)`

```
bIndices = [101, 403,...];  %Vector containing the indices of the peaks in 'tB'
aIndices = [];              %Allocate an empty vector
A = [];                     %Allocate an empty vector
B = [];                     %Allocate an empty vector
for b = bIndices            %This will cycle through all peak indices one at a time setting 'b' to the current single index
    B = [B tB(b)];          %Retrieve the actual time using the index, concatenate it
    for a = 1:length(tA)    %Loop through the entire time vector tA
        if (tA(a) >= tB(b)) %Time is greater than or equal
             %Concatenate the newly found index 'a' from tA to the vector aIndex:
             aIndices = [aIndices a];
             %Concatenate the newly found time 'tA(a)' to the time vector A:
             A = [A tA(a)]; %Or if you want the actual time
             break;         %Exit the inner loop, search for the next index `b`
        end
    end
end
```

At the end, `A` stores an array of peak times matching all the times in `B` (approximately, probably a little later). `A-B` is the discrepancy between the two times (both vectors should be the same length), but it should be pretty small, any zeros would mean the 2 aligned perfectly at those instances. `aIndices` is the corresponding indices of `tA` at the desired time(s). I didn't actually test this code, hopefully my logic is sound.

Comment: Why a loop? Why not `find(tA>B,1,'first')`?

Comment: It's a good shorthand suggestion, but not really great for educational explanation purposes. Give a man a fish or teach a man to fish?

Comment: This is turning out to be difficult for me because I have a vector of where known peaks occur. It's not just one number. Any advice? I tried using 2 for loops and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: See new edits. I didn't test it, but it should work.